# Converting projects that use Png images to D2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Anyone that used the (not anymore) freely available TPngImage by by Gustavo Daud tried porting their projects to Delphi 2009?

In my case, it seems that all TImage png images that displayed just fine in D2007 are now blank when opening the form in D2009 (if I re-add the image in D2009, save the form and open it in D2007 then the image is blank again).

Comparing the Picture.Data between D2007 and D2009 for the exact same images shows that the data is different.

Anyone noticed this problem? I have dozens of png images on all my projects and I would hate to have to re-add them in D2009 and loose backward compatibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just read this blog few minutes ago before see your question, I think it fixes the same problem:

[Converting to D2009: How to keep PNGs in TImage](http://blog.digivendo.com/)